# Symfony 6 UnitTest cannot create database for test environnement

Tags: php, mysql, docker, unit-testing, symfony

I am working on a symfony project and I'm trying to write so unit test. I've followed every tutorials and they all end with having to do the same command at some point which is :

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
```

But I keep getting this error and don't know what to do.

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'db_test'
```

Here is .env:

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=4ad7f4a1f3a580dd3dbcf5636f045612

DATABASE_URL="mysql://user:test@127.0.0.1:3306/db?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.8"

CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$'
```

and .env.test:

```
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st'
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=999999
PANTHER_APP_ENV=panther
PANTHER_ERROR_SCREENSHOT_DIR=./var/error-screenshots
DATABASE_URL="mysql://user:test@127.0.0.1:3306/db?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.8"
```

my phpunit.xml.dist is untouched but here is the important part

```xml
<php>
    <ini name="display_errors" value="1" />
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
    <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
    <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value="" />
    <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="9.5" />
</php>
```

I found this error because when I first tried to launch this unit test :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;

class UserApiTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function getAllUsers(): void
    {
        $response = static::createClient()->request('GET', '/api/users');

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }
}
```

with this command I got this error:

```
C:\User\api> ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite "Project Test Suite"


There was 1 error:

1) App\Tests\UserEntityTest::testSearchByName
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'db_test'
```

I should also add that I'm using Docker for my database:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db:db
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - /sessions

volumes:
    db-data:
```

I don't know what to do I tried everything that I found and nothing seems to work.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I am confused. In your .env files I see DATABASE_URL that point to database called `db`. But your error show different database name. Something is missing?

Comment: @sensorario I'm sorry I changed the name on the other parts but forgot in the error message, DATABASE_URL is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySql User don’t have got a right to create a database ?

An article how to grant your user for this :
https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/

Comment: I forgotted to add that I'm using docker and I don't really know if that's the problem how to do it, I added my docker-compose maybe it will help.

Comment: can you try with your root user mysql in your setting of test ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by that, my mySQL user is defined in docker and it's user:test which is what's written in the .env. If I'm not wrong I am already using my root user.

Comment: Replace user:test by root:test